# controling svg clock with setInterval

Tags: javascript, svg

I made an svg clock :

```
<svg baseProfile="basic" viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="aiguilles">
    <g id="heures" visibility="hidden">
        <path fill="#555" d="M94.9,38.8v11l-6,8.2l6.3,9.3L95,92.9c-2.2,1.6-3.7,4.2-3.7,7.1s1.4,5.5,3.6,7l-0.1,12.7l5.3,3.5v-14.5 c0-4.6,0-13.1,0-17.5V33.9L94.9,38.8z"/>
        <path fill="#bbb" d="M105,92.9l-0.2-25.6l6.3-9.3l-6-8.2v-11l-5.1-5v57.4c0,5.7,0,12,0,17.5v14.5l5.3-3.5l-0.1-12.7 c2.2-1.6,3.6-4.1,3.6-7C108.7,97.1,107.3,94.5,105,92.9z"/>
        <polygon fill="#fff" points="100,69.7 92.6,58.1 100,47.5 107.4,58.1 "/>
    </g>
    <g id="minutes" visibility="hidden">
        <path fill="#777" d="M95.6,9.7v84.9c-1.6,1.3-2.5,3.2-2.5,5.4s1,4.1,2.5,5.4v14.8l4.4,2.6V5.3L95.6,9.7z"/>
        <path fill="#ddd" d="M106.9,100c0-2.1-1-4.1-2.5-5.3v-85L100,5.3V93l0,0c0,3,0,10.4,0,13.9l0,0v15.9l4.4-2.6v-14.9 C105.9,104.1,106.9,102.2,106.9,100z"/>
        <polygon fill="#fff" points="97.7,17.5 97.7,69.4 100,71.9 102.3,69.4 102.3,17.5 100,15.4 "/>
    </g>
    <g id="secondes" visibility="hidden">
        <path fill="#bbb" d="M101,95.5c0-33.1,0-54.1,0-67.4c2.5-0.5,4.4-2.7,4.4-5.3s-1.9-4.8-4.4-5.3c0-12.4,0-12.7,0-13.3 c0-0.8-0.5-1.8-1-2c-0.6,0.3-1,1.2-1,2c0,0.6,0,0.9,0,13.3c-2.5,0.5-4.4,2.7-4.4,5.3s1.9,4.8,4.4,5.3c0,13.3,0,34.3,0,67.4 c-2.2,0.5-3.8,2.4-3.8,4.7c0,1.2,0.5,2.3,1.2,3.1V122l3.7,3.3l3.7-3.3v-18.7c0.7-0.8,1.2-1.9,1.2-3.1 C104.8,97.9,103.2,95.9,101,95.5z"/>
        <circle fill="#FFF" cx="100" cy="22.7" r="3.7"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

and I suceeded in animating the hands so that they first go from 12:00 to the current time with the "toTimeNow" function and then show the time continuously with the "timeNow" function :

```
var tailleAiguilles = 2;
    var aiguillesGauche = 250;
    var aiguillesHaut = 250;
    var aiguilles = document.getElementById("aiguilles");
    function transformSvg() {
        aiguilles.setAttribute("transform", "matrix(" + tailleAiguilles + " 0 0 " + tailleAiguilles + " " + aiguillesGauche + " " + aiguillesHaut + ")");
    }

    function toTimeNow() {
        var hr = 0;
        var mn = 0;
        var sc = 0;
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            var maintenant = new Date();
            var heures = maintenant.getHours();
            var minutes = maintenant.getMinutes();
            var secondes = maintenant.getSeconds();
            var milliSecondes = maintenant.getMilliseconds();
            var secondes2 = 6 * secondes;
            if  (heures * 30 + minutes * 0.5 > 359) {
                var angleHeures = heures * 30 + minutes * 0.5 - 359;
            }
            else {
                var angleHeures = heures * 30 + minutes * 0.5;
            }
            var angleMinutes = minutes * 6 + (0.1 * secondes);
            var angleSecondes = secondes2 += 0.006 * milliSecondes;
            var max = Math.max(angleHeures, angleMinutes, angleSecondes)
            if  (hr < angleHeures) {
                hr += angleHeures / max * 2;
                rotation('heures', hr, 100);
            }
            if  (mn < angleMinutes) {
                mn += angleMinutes / max * 2;
                rotation('minutes', mn, 100);
            }
            if  (sc < angleSecondes) {
                sc += angleSecondes / max * 2;
                rotation('secondes', sc, 100);
            }
            else  {
                clearInterval(interval);
                timeNow();
            }
        }, 5);
    }

    function timeNow() {
        setInterval(function() {
            var maintenant = new Date();
            var heures = maintenant.getHours();
            var minutes = maintenant.getMinutes();
            var secondes = maintenant.getSeconds();
            var milliSecondes = maintenant.getMilliseconds();
            var secondes2 = 6 * secondes;
            rotation('heures', heures * 30 + minutes * 0.5, 100);
            rotation('minutes', minutes * 6 + (0.1 * secondes), 100);
            rotation('secondes', secondes2 += 0.006 * milliSecondes, 100);
        }, 50);
    }

    function rotation(id, angle, centre) {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        if (element) {
            element.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate(' + angle + ', ' + centre + ', ' + centre + ')');
            if (element.getAttribute('visibility') == 'hidden') {
                element.setAttribute('visibility', 'visible');
            }
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', toTimeNow, false);
```

But I noticed that just before the 2nd function takes over the hands move slightly backwards. If somebody could tell me why I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Which one of heures/minutes/secondes is moving backwards? I'm rather suspicious of `secondes2`. Your 2nd interval function repeats a lot of the 1st one. If you refactor them into a single function, you may fix your issue.

Comment: All of them and it seems to be more or less pronounced at each reload. There is an example here : http://mussoft.ch/tuts/bannieresWeb/timeNow-LonHydro.html. Your probably right in that I would have to make one big function. I may get around to it when I finish setting up the dynamic lighting on the hands.

Comment: https://mussoft.ch/tuts/bannieresWeb/LonHC11Countdown/timeNow-LonHydroSlow.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost certainly because of this code:

```
if  (mn < angleMinutes) {
   mn += angleMinutes / max * 2;
   rotation('minutes', mn, 100);
}
```

If `mn` is slightly less than `angleMinutes`, then this code can result in it stepping well past it.  You should check `mn` after you increment it.

```
if  (mn < angleMinutes) {
   mn = Math.min(angleMinutes, mn + angleMinutes / max * 2);
   rotation('minutes', mn, 100);
}
```

Comment: I replaced that line with the one you suggested (in the toTimeNow function) but the minute-hand just gets stuck on the actual time instead of rotating to it from 12. I also put two console.log for the minute-angle variable. one in toTimeNow & one in timeNow. I can see now in the chrome-inspector the difference betwwen the end of the first function (toTimeNow) and when The second function (timeNow) takes over. My solution was to speed-up the stepinterval of toTimeNow, as it seems to lessen that difference. I still don't get why there is a difference though.

Comment: You can check the slow version here : http://mussoft.ch/tuts/bannieresWeb/timeNow-LonHydroSlow.html. I also put the cosole.log in the normal-speedy version (see link above).
As a side note, there is a bug (I think) in chrome 67. The clippath svg element doesn't move.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. That should have been `Math.min()` not `Math.max()`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks